# Проблема с выводом данных и базы данных в python

Tags: mysql, python, python-3.x

```
cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM scores')
results = cursor.fetchall()

for row in results:
    houseID = row[0]
    houseName = row[1]
    houseScore = row[2]

    print(str(houseID) + '\t' + str(houseName) + '\t' + str(houseScore))

conn.close()
```

То что вывело:

```
1b'Griffin'1000
2b'Dragon'900
3b'Phoenix'800
4b'Pegasus'700
```

Нужно вывести без буквы 'b' и кавычек

Comment: Какая кодировка стоит у вас в MySql скорее всего `cp1250` попробуйте поставить `utf8_general_ci`

Comment: Поставил, всё та же проблема

Comment: 1- убедитесь что текстовый тип в houseName в БД используется 2- убедитесь что как Unicode а не как bytes в Питон возвращается.

Answer (score 1):

Решение в лоб, вызвать на каждой `house*` переменной метод `decode()`, потому что сейчас у вас там байты. Такое бывает, если тип поля БД бинарный.

Answer (score 1):

В методе pymysql.connect есть 2 параметра связанных с кодировкой:
`charset` и `use_unicode`

**charset** - это кодировка в которой работает клиент. Т. е. Все строки которые передаёт клиент будут трактоваться серверовм именно в этой кодировке и все строковые результаты будут конвертироваться перед отдачей клиенту в неё же.

**use_unicode** - использовать unicode строки или byte.

Соответственно, чтобы комфортно работать в python3 со строками (они unicode), нужно при подключении указать `use_unicode=True` и `charset='кодировка_базы'`

Answer (score 0):

Примерно вот так. Ну, исключениями сами додумаете, полагаю, как обложить.

```
import pandas as pd
import pymysql as sql
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

login = 'YOURLOGIN'
pass = 'YOURPASS'
host = 'YOURHOST'
db_name = 'YOURDB'

db_connection = create_engine('mysql+pymysql://'+{MYLOGIN}+':'+{MYPASS}+'@'+{MYHOST}+':3306/{DB}'.format(MYLOGIN=login,MYPASS=pass,MYHOST=host,DB=db_name),encoding='utf8',echo=False)

df = pd.read_sql("""SELECT * FROM scores""", db_connection)
print(df)
```